# javascript forEach on array / json data but sortby latest date?

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to modify the following so that on the foreach it would reverse so that latest date of data is first rather than oldest to newest?

```js
var json = {
  "TrackingRecord": {
    "Authorised": "Authorised(5.77.48.131)",
    "DeliveryAddress": {
      "CompanyName": "JAMES DERICK",
      "Address1": "6",
      "Address2": "LIBER HOUSE",
      "Address3": "OLYMPIAN",
      "Town": "YORK",
      "Postcode": "YO10 3UF",
      "ContactName": "JAMES DERICK",
      "ContactTelephone": "7507346318"
    },
    "CollectionAddress": {
      "CompanyName": "AMBIENT LOUNGE LTD",
      "Address1": "UNIT 3 LONG HEDGE LANE INDUSTR",
      "Address2": "BOTTESFORD",
      "Address3": {

      },
      "Town": "NOTTINGHAM",
      "Postcode": "NG13 0BF",
      "ContactName": "SARAH KIRBY",
      "ContactTelephone": "07879 442266074"
    },
    "ConsignmentInformation": {
      "Pieces": "1",
      "Pallets": "0",
      "Weight": "10",
      "Service": "Priority 1",
      "DeliveryDate": "2016-02-29T00:00:00",
      "ItemsDelivered": "1",
      "ConsignmentRef": "2838",
      "SpecialInstructions": "JAMES DERICK 7507346318 {JAMES\u003Cbr\u003E14075@GMAIL.COM}\u003Cbr\u003E",
      "AdditionalReferencesInformation": {
        "AdditionalReferences": {
          "Reference": "2838"
        }
      }
    },
    "MovementInformation": {
      "Movement": [{
        "MovementDate": "2016-02-25T00:00:00",
        "MovementTime": "0001-01-01T10:00:04",
        "Description": "Created By EZEEWEB",
        "DeliveryDepot": "Leeds",
        "Round": "019",
        "DeliveryDate": "2016-02-26T00:00:00",
        "PackagesReceived": "0",
        "PackagesDelivered": "0"
      }, {
        "MovementDate": "2016-02-26T00:00:00",
        "MovementTime": "0001-01-01T07:11:53",
        "Description": "Out to deliver",
        "DeliveryDepot": "Leeds",
        "Round": "019",
        "DeliveryDate": "2016-02-26T00:00:00",
        "PackagesReceived": "1",
        "PackagesDelivered": "0"
      }, {
        "MovementDate": "2016-02-26T00:00:00",
        "MovementTime": "0001-01-01T11:00:53",
        "Description": "Failed - Other reason",
        "DeliveryDepot": "Leeds",
        "Round": "019",
        "DeliveryDate": "2016-02-29T00:00:00",
        "PackagesReceived": "1",
        "PackagesDelivered": "0"
      }, {
        "MovementDate": "2016-02-27T00:00:00",
        "MovementTime": "0001-01-01T05:59:32",
        "Description": "Out to deliver",
        "DeliveryDepot": "Leeds",
        "Round": "019",
        "DeliveryDate": "2016-02-29T00:00:00",
        "PackagesReceived": "1",
        "PackagesDelivered": "0"
      }, {
        "MovementDate": "2016-02-29T00:00:00",
        "MovementTime": "0001-01-01T10:55:43",
        "Description": "Delivered",
        "DeliveryDepot": "Leeds",
        "Round": "019",
        "DeliveryDate": "2016-02-29T00:00:00",
        "PackagesReceived": "1",
        "PackagesDelivered": "1"
      }]
    },
    "TimedInformation": {
      "TimedDelivery": {
        "Signature": "DERICK",
        "SignatureDate": "2016-02-29T00:00:00",
        "SignatureTime": "0001-01-01T10:55:00"
      }
    },
    "ScanInformation": {
      "Scan": [{
        "PieceID": "148426702251072001",
        "Description": "Auto Inbound Scan   ()",
        "Depot": "Newark",
        "ScanDate": "2016-02-25T00:00:00",
        "ScanTime": "0001-01-01T17:12:01",
        "ScannedBy": "NWK CONVYR"
      }, {
        "PieceID": "148426702251072001",
        "Description": "Auto Inbound Scan   ()",
        "Depot": "Leeds",
        "ScanDate": "2016-02-26T00:00:00",
        "ScanTime": "0001-01-01T02:22:08",
        "ScannedBy": "LDS CONVYR"
      }, {
        "PieceID": "148426702251072001",
        "Description": "Load C & D          (019)",
        "Depot": "Leeds",
        "ScanDate": "2016-02-26T00:00:00",
        "ScanTime": "0001-01-01T03:37:45",
        "ScannedBy": "CJONES"
      }, {
        "PieceID": "148426702251072001",
        "Description": "Load C & D          (019)",
        "Depot": "Leeds",
        "ScanDate": "2016-02-26T00:00:00",
        "ScanTime": "0001-01-01T23:43:22",
        "ScannedBy": "CJONES"
      }]
    },
    "ImageInformation": {
      "PODImage": {
        "URL": "http:\/\/www.tpeweb.co.uk\/ezpod\/tpenas\/valid\/20160229\/014842672838___________00000_01.tif"
      }
    }
  }
}



json.TrackingRecord.MovementInformation.Movement.forEach(function(item) {
  //console.log(item);
  item.MovementDate = moment(item.MovementDate).format('ddd, Do of MMM YYYY');
  item.MovementTime = moment(item.MovementTime).format('hh:mm a');
  $("#movement tbody").append("<tr><td>" + item.MovementDate + "</td><td>" + item.MovementTime + "</td><td>" + item.Description + "</td></tr>");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="movement">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with plain `forEach`. Possibilities:

- Assume it is in ascending order. Loop indices from `length - 1` to `0`. Nondestructive.
- Assume it is in ascending order. Apply `reverse`, then `forEach`. Destructive.
- Assume it is unsorted. Sort the array, then apply `forEach`. Destructive.
- Assume it is unsorted. Create an array of indices, sort the indices by the corresponding values in the array, apply `forEach` on indices and access array members. Nondestructive.
- Assume it is unsorted. Clone the array using `slice`, then apply `sort` and `forEach`. Nondestructive.

Comment: Accepted as valid Answer and good definition, just  quick one though... im new with JS / jQuery.... more history with jQuery and not seen this method before so am i right in thinking his is more standard JS and that above is standard JS?

Comment: `forEach` is standard JavaScript 1.6 (EcmaScript 5.1).

Comment: Ahh good to know! seems lot cleaner, nicer than previous JS versions and i feel currently easier than jQuery foreach loops etc... thanks for clarifying!

Comment: It will be even cleaner in the future (as ES6 acceptance spreads): `array.forEach(x => console.log(x))`. Also, a community consensus on SO is that only questions tagged with [tag:jquery] can have jQuery answers (and someone will usually leave an offending answer a polite reminder of that).

Comment: must admit, not touched looked at native JS for a long time and just been working with jQuery but just this 1 thing has massively pushed me back to it because was so much smarter to just achieve this one thing i needed! Have i become lazy!? lol

Comment: jQuery is also JavaScript, it's just a library, not a separate language. I also use it on pretty much every project, because it simplifies many common tasks (e.g. `$('table').append('<tr><td>foo</td></tr>')` is like ten lines in pure JS. Okay, not really, but you know what I mean. :P). But knowing your language well is also a tremendous boost, whether or not you use libraries.

Comment: @Amadan—10 lines? 3 statements: `table.insertRow`, `row.insertCell`, `cell.appendChild` which can be chained as a single statement if you like (I don't).

Comment: @RobG: Exaggeration, for sure; it's what popped into by mind first. `$(document).on('click', '.p[data-type!="comment"] input', handler)` might be a better example.

Answer (score 1):

You could change

```
json.TrackingRecord.MovementInformation.Movement.forEach(function(item) {
```

to

```
json.TrackingRecord.MovementInformation.Movement.reverse().forEach(function(item) {
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
var json = {
  "TrackingRecord": {
    "Authorised": "Authorised(5.77.48.131)",
    "DeliveryAddress": {
      "CompanyName": "JAMES DERICK",
      "Address1": "6",
      "Address2": "LIBER HOUSE",
      "Address3": "OLYMPIAN",
      "Town": "YORK",
      "Postcode": "YO10 3UF",
      "ContactName": "JAMES DERICK",
      "ContactTelephone": "7507346318"
    },
    "CollectionAddress": {
      "CompanyName": "AMBIENT LOUNGE LTD",
      "Address1": "UNIT 3 LONG HEDGE LANE INDUSTR",
      "Address2": "BOTTESFORD",
      "Address3": {

      },
      "Town": "NOTTINGHAM",
      "Postcode": "NG13 0BF",
      "ContactName": "SARAH KIRBY",
      "ContactTelephone": "07879 442266074"
    },
    "ConsignmentInformation": {
      "Pieces": "1",
      "Pallets": "0",
      "Weight": "10",
      "Service": "Priority 1",
      "DeliveryDate": "2016-02-29T00:00:00",
      "ItemsDelivered": "1",
      "ConsignmentRef": "2838",
      "SpecialInstructions": "JAMES DERICK 7507346318 {JAMES\u003Cbr\u003E14075@GMAIL.COM}\u003Cbr\u003E",
      "AdditionalReferencesInformation": {
        "AdditionalReferences": {
          "Reference": "2838"
        }
      }
    },
    "MovementInformation": {
      "Movement": [{
        "MovementDate": "2016-02-25T00:00:00",
        "MovementTime": "0001-01-01T10:00:04",
        "Description": "Created By EZEEWEB",
        "DeliveryDepot": "Leeds",
        "Round": "019",
        "DeliveryDate": "2016-02-26T00:00:00",
        "PackagesReceived": "0",
        "PackagesDelivered": "0"
      }, {
        "MovementDate": "2016-02-26T00:00:00",
        "MovementTime": "0001-01-01T07:11:53",
        "Description": "Out to deliver",
        "DeliveryDepot": "Leeds",
        "Round": "019",
        "DeliveryDate": "2016-02-26T00:00:00",
        "PackagesReceived": "1",
        "PackagesDelivered": "0"
      }, {
        "MovementDate": "2016-02-26T00:00:00",
        "MovementTime": "0001-01-01T11:00:53",
        "Description": "Failed - Other reason",
        "DeliveryDepot": "Leeds",
        "Round": "019",
        "DeliveryDate": "2016-02-29T00:00:00",
        "PackagesReceived": "1",
        "PackagesDelivered": "0"
      }, {
        "MovementDate": "2016-02-27T00:00:00",
        "MovementTime": "0001-01-01T05:59:32",
        "Description": "Out to deliver",
        "DeliveryDepot": "Leeds",
        "Round": "019",
        "DeliveryDate": "2016-02-29T00:00:00",
        "PackagesReceived": "1",
        "PackagesDelivered": "0"
      }, {
        "MovementDate": "2016-02-29T00:00:00",
        "MovementTime": "0001-01-01T10:55:43",
        "Description": "Delivered",
        "DeliveryDepot": "Leeds",
        "Round": "019",
        "DeliveryDate": "2016-02-29T00:00:00",
        "PackagesReceived": "1",
        "PackagesDelivered": "1"
      }]
    },
    "TimedInformation": {
      "TimedDelivery": {
        "Signature": "DERICK",
        "SignatureDate": "2016-02-29T00:00:00",
        "SignatureTime": "0001-01-01T10:55:00"
      }
    },
    "ScanInformation": {
      "Scan": [{
        "PieceID": "148426702251072001",
        "Description": "Auto Inbound Scan   ()",
        "Depot": "Newark",
        "ScanDate": "2016-02-25T00:00:00",
        "ScanTime": "0001-01-01T17:12:01",
        "ScannedBy": "NWK CONVYR"
      }, {
        "PieceID": "148426702251072001",
        "Description": "Auto Inbound Scan   ()",
        "Depot": "Leeds",
        "ScanDate": "2016-02-26T00:00:00",
        "ScanTime": "0001-01-01T02:22:08",
        "ScannedBy": "LDS CONVYR"
      }, {
        "PieceID": "148426702251072001",
        "Description": "Load C & D          (019)",
        "Depot": "Leeds",
        "ScanDate": "2016-02-26T00:00:00",
        "ScanTime": "0001-01-01T03:37:45",
        "ScannedBy": "CJONES"
      }, {
        "PieceID": "148426702251072001",
        "Description": "Load C & D          (019)",
        "Depot": "Leeds",
        "ScanDate": "2016-02-26T00:00:00",
        "ScanTime": "0001-01-01T23:43:22",
        "ScannedBy": "CJONES"
      }]
    },
    "ImageInformation": {
      "PODImage": {
        "URL": "http:\/\/www.tpeweb.co.uk\/ezpod\/tpenas\/valid\/20160229\/014842672838___________00000_01.tif"
      }
    }
  }
}



json.TrackingRecord.MovementInformation.Movement.reverse().forEach(function(item) {
  //console.log(item);
  item.MovementDate = moment(item.MovementDate).format('ddd, Do of MMM YYYY');
  item.MovementTime = moment(item.MovementTime).format('hh:mm a');
  $("#movement tbody").append("<tr><td>" + item.MovementDate + "</td><td>" + item.MovementTime + "</td><td>" + item.Description + "</td></tr>");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="movement">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Keep in mind that `reverse` actually modifies the array, it doesn't just return an array with the elements reversed. However, this is probably what you want considering it's supposed to be printed in that order.

Comment: Ahh much easier than i thought it would be! worked a treat! thanks for your help mate!

Comment: I wont consider, i will make it an accepted answer... but i have to wait 9 minutes so bear with me :)

Comment: @James Oh shoot, I forgot Stack Exchange worked that way! I've been on a hiatus, sorry!

Comment: Note that *reverse* modifies the array.

Comment: @RobG Yeah, I should note that in my answer

Comment: Ahh ok good to know, should be ok in this case as this loop is only for tracking data and i felt needed to show latest at top but the rest of the array is parent level so should be ok and seems ok.

Comment: @James Amadan's answer is more informational, so I would consider marking his as accepted instead and maybe just giving me an upvote

Comment: @James I'm glad to hear that it worked for you, but Amadan's answer is really just more helpful to posterity :)

Comment: Done, i thought you could mark both but must be wrong lol up-voted and marked his anyway. Thanks though for your help mate! again!!!

Comment: @James No problem, you can read this to understand more about the "accepted" answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

A non–destructive way to iterate backwards over an array (other than a plain for loop) is *reduceRight*:

```
json.TrackingRecord.MovementInformation.Movement.reduceRight(function(acc, item) {
  // do stuff
}, null);
```